# What happened to Dirk Willems' family after his martyrdom?

Tags: religion, protestant-church, reformation, netherlands

From Wikipedia

> [Dirk Willems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Willems) 
>   was a Dutch martyred Anabaptist who is most famous for escaping from prison, turning around to rescue his pursuer —who had fallen through thin ice while chasing Willems— to then be recaptured, tortured and killed for his faith.

What happened to his family after his death?  Did he have any family?

Comment: "Martyrs Mirror: A Social History" on GoogleBooks, p. 284 [ goo.gl/PT3W75 ] names his children as Peter and Nelleken, in a passage from a drama on Dirk Willems' life by James Juhnke.